# In Mongodb, how do I aggregate to count distinct items per-group?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a pipeline, the following grouping

```
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$salesperson", 
        "items": {
            $push: "$city"
        }
    }
}
```

produces results like below:

```
{
    "_id":"Fred",
    "items": ["Boston", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Boston"]
},
{
    "_id":"Mary",
    "items": ["Austin", "Chicago", "Austin", "Louisville"]
}
```

I want to count **distinct** cities for each salesperson so that I would get this:

```
[
    {
        "Fred":2
    }, 
    {
        "Mary":3
    }
]
```

**How can the pipeline be modified to achieve that?**

**Edit:** After using `$addToSet` as recommended, I get a pipeline like the following:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "field1": {
            "$in": ["a", "b", "c"]
          }
        },
        {
          "field2": {
            "$in": ["d", "e"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$salesperson",
      "items": {
        "$addToSet": "$city"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**How can I count items in each set, per group?**

Comment: Do you want items array to have duplicates and additionally get the distinct value count or is it ok to have only unique values(cities) in items array ?

Comment: How ```$group: {_id: "$salesperson", items: {$push: "$city"}}``` is producing output like this ```[{"Fred": ["Boston", "Chicago", "Chicago, "Boston"]}, {"Mary":["Austin", "Chicago, "Austin", "Louisville"]}]``` ?
**Please share complete information.**

Comment: @srinivasy uniques are all that matter.

Comment: @JoshuaFox I have updated the answer. have a look at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going in good direction, just instead of $push (which add the field in an array), you need to use $addToSet (which will add unique fields in the array).

```
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$salesperson", 
        "items": {
            $addToSet: "$city"
        }
    }
}
```

now it will produce the result:

```
{
    "_id":"Fred",
    "items": ["Boston", "Chicago"]
},
{
    "_id":"Mary",
    "items": ["Austin", "Chicago", "Louisville"]
}
```

and in the next stage, you can count the elements in the array like you are doing already

Here I'm adding the complete query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$salesperson", 
            "items": {
                $addToSet: "$city"
            }
        }
    },
    {
      $group:{ 
        "_id":null,
        "data":{
            $push:{
                "k":"$_id",
                "v":{
                    $size:"$items"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    },
    {
        $project:{ 
            "data":{
                $arrayToObject:"$data"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":"$data"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

And it will give you the output:

```
{ "Fred" : 2, "Mary" : 3 }
```

Hope it will help you. And for more refer [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Comment: Thanks! $addToSet uniquifies the values.  But   your $project clause includes data-values -- how can I use that in a pipeline?

Comment: @JoshuaFox please share your complete query and data so that I could refactor your query and we can conclude to the solution.

Comment: I added the query (pipeline). The actual pipeline has many more clauses in the $and , but this represents the $match-and$group structure correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Two comments: (1) Your first codeblock has  $push, but I think that $addToSet is needed; and (2) for clarity, could you merge your first codeblock in the the third (the aggregate() call, where this $group should come in the array before the second group.

Comment: @JoshuaFox haha, It seems like $addToSet was replaced in the last edit. I have updated the answer with the complete query.